# How can i get the default accent color in Windows 10?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

I have an application and i want to make its background color as default Windows 10 *Accent* color and when user changes Windows 10's *Accent* color i want my application's background color also changes.

[image]

Comment: From your graphic, it looks like you are selecting the _Accent_ color from the Colors settings page and not the the background color from the Background settings page.  Getting the background color is easy, whereas getting the accent color is more involved.

Comment: Yes i need accent color

Answer (score 1):

You would need to make a call to `UISettings.GetColorValue(UIColorType.Background)` as documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.viewmanagement.uisettings.getcolorvalue#Windows_UI_ViewManagement_UISettings_GetColorValue_Windows_UI_ViewManagement_UIColorType_).

Comment: Ah, but just setting a color to this value won’t make it update when the user changes the Windows 10 background color, so this answer is incomplete

Answer (score 1):

WinForms is an old technology that has not been updated much to support new OS features.  There is no good way to get the *Accent* color using the base .Net libraries (though there is an registry based hack using undocumented keys to retrieve the value). Fortunately, you can access some of the Windows Runtime APIs by adding the NUGET package [Microsoft.Windows.SDK.Contracts](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Windows.SDK.Contracts/).

With this package added, you can create an instance of the [Windows.UI.ViewManagement.UISettings Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.ViewManagement.UISettings) and then use the [UISettings.GetColorValue(UIColorType) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.viewmanagement.uisettings.getcolorvalue) to retrieve the value.

To be notified of changes to the value, you can subscribe to the [SystemEvents.UserPreferenceChanged Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.systemevents.userpreferencechanged?view=netframework-4.8).  This event categorizes the change as a [UserPreferenceCategory.General](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.userpreferencecategory?view=netframework-4.8) type change that is the default when the old logic does not know what has changed (again old code not updated for new features).  You could detect changes by listenimg for the [WM_SETTINGCHANGE   message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-settingchange) and check for when the WParam is null and the LParam points to a string ("ImmersiveColorSet"), but this replies upon the string value never changing and is not much better than reacting to all UserPreferenceCategory.General changes.

With all that stated, a simple implementation would be as follows:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        UserPreferenceChangedEventHandler UserPerferenceChanged = (s, e) =>
        { if (e.Category == UserPreferenceCategory.General || e.Category == UserPreferenceCategory.VisualStyle) BackColor = GetAccentColor(); };

        SystemEvents.UserPreferenceChanged += UserPerferenceChanged;
        Disposed += (object s, EventArgs e) => { SystemEvents.UserPreferenceChanged -= UserPerferenceChanged; };
    }

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);
        BackColor = GetAccentColor();
    }

    static Windows.UI.ViewManagement.UISettings uiSettings = new Windows.UI.ViewManagement.UISettings();
    private static System.Drawing.Color GetAccentColor()
    {
        Windows.UI.Color c = uiSettings.GetColorValue(Windows.UI.ViewManagement.UIColorType.Accent);
        return Color.FromArgb(c.A, c.R, c.G, c.B);
    }
}
```

Comment: You said WinForm is old tech, what does it mean? I am new in programming i want to create Windwos application. Can you advice me about new tech to create Window Application?

Comment: @MahmoodGaribov - I probably should have called it a mature UI technology that wraps even older Win32 API's and that it gets few updates.  It only started to get high DPI support a few years ago, and even that is somewhat limited.  That said, it is still a viable platform for simple projects that do not require fancy graphical interfaces. You can add functionality to it, but that requires custom coding (i.e. do not expect a feature to be added just because you want it).  XAML based GUI's (such as WPF and UWP) are supposedly the recommend path forward for desktop applications.

Answer (score 0):

You can override `WndProc` to handle the [`WM_SETTINGCHANGE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-settingchange) message.
When this message is received, you can determine whether the settings change is related to a Desktop change inspecting the Message `WParam`: if it's [`SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-systemparametersinfow), then Desktop settings have changed.

A change in the Background Color is notified like this.
When you get the message, the Color value has already been changed so you can retrive it using the [SystemColors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.systemcolors) class: **`SystemColors.Desktop`** returns the current Color of the Desktop.

```
private const int WM_SETTINGCHANGE = 0x001A;
private const int SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER = 0x0014;

protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    base.WndProc(ref m);
    switch (m.Msg) {
        case WM_SETTINGCHANGE:
            if (m.WParam.ToInt32() == SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER) {
                this.BackColor = SystemColors.Desktop;
            }
            m.Result = IntPtr.Zero;
            break;
        // other case switches
}
```